# Reactivating Held Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can a Held Subscriber be reactivated?

Tried importing into the All Subs from a Child Business Unit and the import couldn't find the subscriber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a CSV import to the AllSubs list.  Have a column for Subscriber Key and Status, and make the value of status "Active". for each row  Import that into all subs, using update.

Good luck!

Comment: This works if the import occurs on the Enterprise MID All Subs but not from the Child MID All Subs.  Any reason why we would see such behavior?

Comment: Yes.  There really is only one true "all subs" list, the enterprise one.  While it may seem that there is a Child BU all subs list, that really isn't the case.  Once a send is being processed, everything goes through the Enterprise level..  Hope this helps!