# How to resubscribe user after a soft bounce

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, unsubscriber

I recently had a subscriber reach out because they stopped receiving our email updates and they were not sure why. When I locate their details under 'All Subscribers' I can see that they have had 3 soft bounces. Is there any way for me to be able to resubscribe them? I.e. turn their grey icon green again.

Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy wayto do it in the UI.  You would need to add via a CSV import to all subscribers. In this CSV you will need to add a column named "Status" and fill this field with the value of "Active".  Make sure that you do 'add and update' or 'update only' or it will not overwrite the status.

Similar question/answer here: [Reactivating Held Subscriber](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60792/reactivating-held-subscriber)